# Can someone explain why this particular php array will not encode to json correctly using json_encode?

Tags: php, json

This is the array I get from a remote api call:

```
Array ( [49] => Array ( [username] => Rocky [email] => rocky@rocky.com ) [50] => Array ( [username] => Ricky [email] => ricky@ricky.com ) )
```

json_encode gives me this:

```
"Array\n(\n [49] => Array\n (\n [username] => Rocky\n [email] => rocky@rocky.com\n )\n\n [50] => Array\n (\n [username] => Ricky\n [email] => ricky@ricky.com\n )\n\n)\n"
```

I need json that can be accessed remotely as an object, but this string is not working.

I am accessing this data using this curl request:

```
<?php 

$post = [
    'api_key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    ];

$host = "http://xxxxxxxxxx.com/yardsale/get_clients.php";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);


    echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: can you also post the php that would produce this output?

Comment: You're literally encoding a string, so you're getting a string as output. You need to encode the actual array, not the string version of it (which looks like `print_r` output). You should be getting JSON or maybe XML from the API, not the string you pasted above.

Comment: https://eval.in/618944.  it's working with your given data. so check what others commented above

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem of array, you can change the array format something like that:-

```
<?php 
$arr=array( '49' => array('username'=> 'rocky', 'email'=> 'rocky@rocky.com'),'50' => array('username'=> 'mohit', 'email'=> 'mohit@mohit.com'));
$test_arr= json_encode($arr);
echo $test_arr;
?>
```

And the output of the above json :

```
{"49":{"username":"rocky","email":"rocky@rocky.com"},"50":{"username":"mohit","email":"mohit@mohit.com"}}
```